# How can I build a price feed oracle for my Substrate chain?

Tags: runtime, oracles

What components do I need to implement an oracle for a Substrate chain, such as a price feed? I'm looking to understand the general steps and considerations I should make. What libraries or projects already exists that I could use?

Answer (score 3):

There is an implementation of a price feed pallet in the Chainlink-Substrate integration. It connects to and uses the Chainlink oracle network to fetch the price feed.

You can follow a similar approach to build an oracle pallet to connect to any service or oracle for getting data in the chain.
Here is the code - https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-polkadot

Also, here is a good tutorial that explains the process - https://github.com/LaurentTrk/chainlink-substrate-tutorial

This could be a bit outdated considering the evolving code. But the overall approach still makes sense.

Also, as an alternative, you can look at Substrate off-chain workers for getting data via http calls. Here is a good overview - https://docs.substrate.io/v3/concepts/off-chain-features/

These are just some examples, and could be useful in understanding how to approach building your own price-feed or any other oracle integration.

Comment: I believe Sacha is asking how to build a feed oracle rather than how to connect to Chainlink

Comment: As I said in my answer, "You can follow a similar approach to build an oracle". The chainlink implementation is shared as a reference.

Answer (score 3):

- [orml-oracle](https://github.com/open-web3-stack/open-runtime-module-library/tree/master/oracle) pallet template from the Open Runtime Module Library (ORML), which is a community maintained collection of Substrate runtime modules, shows the foundations of how to create an oracle to make off-chain data available on-chain using off-chain workers.
- [substrate-price-oracle](https://github.com/shawntabrizi/substrate-price-oracle/blob/master/src/lib.rs) by Shawn Tabrizi shows specifically how to create an oracle that fetches off-chain price data and stores it on-chain using offchain workers.
- [pallet-chainlink-feed](https://github.com/smartcontractkit/chainlink-polkadot/pull/44/files) by Chainlink is a more complex example of how to create an oracle that fetches off-chain price data and interacts with a seperate token pallet for separation of concerns.
- [example-offchain-worker](https://github.com/paritytech/substrate/tree/master/frame/examples/offchain-worker) pallet and numerous online tutorials with Tomasz Drwięga show how to use an oracle to fetch data from an external API using off-chain workers and store it on-chain.