# How to fetch data through api?

Tags: offchain-worker, substrate-recipes, oracles

I want to fetch the data through an api in our chain. More specifically, I have an api which gives me the latest news. How can i implement this in our substrate chain?
can we have any doc or resources which helps in doing this?

Answer (score 2):

In the Substrate docs you have this example [Make offchain HTTP requests](https://docs.substrate.io/reference/how-to-guides/offchain-workers/offchain-http-requests/) that shows you an example on how to retrieve the price of Bitcoin from the cryptocompare API and how to submit data using an offchain worker API.
With the [code example](https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/master/substrate/frame/examples/offchain-worker/src/lib.rs) in the polkadot-sdk repo.

Before use offchain workers I strongly recommend to read this forum post: [Offchain Workers: Design Assumptions & Vulnerabilities](https://forum.polkadot.network/t/offchain-workers-design-assumptions-vulnerabilities/2548)

Comment: Can i directly call api in the pallet?

Comment: Example: https://github.com/jimmychu0807/substrate-offchain-worker-demo/blob/master/pallets/ocw/src/lib.rs#L363-#L401

Comment: thank you so much for your response.  Can I fetch the data without using the offchain workers?

Comment: No, the runtime's state transition function must be deterministic, and using it directly wont be

Comment: ok got it thank you so much. Is there any other way to fetch data and integrate an api in our chain?

Comment: I am not very familiar with Oracles to be honest, but check this SE question: https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/965/how-can-i-build-a-price-feed-oracle-for-my-substrate-chain