# How to feed private data(confidential information) in Substrate chain through oracle?

Tags: substrate-node-template, offchain-worker, oracles

Is there any Oracle solution available to feed private data to Substrate chain?

Feeding data to chain has already been answered here [How can I build a price feed oracle for my Substrate chain?](https://substrate.stackexchange.com/questions/965/how-can-i-build-a-price-feed-oracle-for-my-substrate-chain). And OCW provides the best solution.

But in my case, I want to feed private data, which is a confidential information. I have checked off chain worker example. We can hit http end point to fetch information https://github.com/paritytech/polkadot-sdk/blob/ca382f32033d8350d49934b30680d8c30dd9bdfc/substrate/frame/examples/offchain-worker/src/lib.rs#L585 and feed on chain.

In my case, I would need confidential information from other application so I can not use http end. I would need any oracle to feed such data on chain.

Please help me to provide the solution.

Comment: Are there any constraints? Can your oracle just encrypt the data before putting it on-chain?

Comment: Yes. We have to send data without encrypt it.

Comment: You want to send data unencrypted data to a public blockchain, but at the same time have it be confidential / private? It sounds like there's a problem here :)

Answer (score 1):

Substrate chains are public. If you want to do confidential computing then you could consider the Phala parachain. They have confidential off-chain computation extensions.

> I can't use OCW.

Without elaboration on *why*, its difficult to give advice.

Another way would be to implement Zero-Knowledge computation to do the computations on-chain. AFAIK its quite computational expensive and normally on-chain code should only verify - not compute. This is a standard principle to make the system more efficient.
You could therefore try to do the computation off-chain and then only have the verification in a on-chain ZK logic, but i dont think its easy...

Next time please include concrete information on what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have updated the description.

Comment: It is still not clear. Confidential to *whom*? To the runtime business logic of the chain, to the OCW, to the other party?  
Who encrypts the data and who should be able to decode it?  
I dont think the question can be answered like this since "confidential" is not sufficiently explained here.